# Formatting file input to a required output using shell script

Tags: bash, shell, unix, awk, sh

I need to format the given input to shown output.  How can I do it?

Input:

```
\n    \abc\:\abc_2\,\n    \rick\:\rick_1\,\n    \harry\:\harry_1\,\n    \Christine\:\Christine_2\,\n
```

[image]

Comment: Is the input format a single line laden with backslashes and other special characters?  If not, what does it look like?  Which tools are you thinking of using (`sed`, `awk`, `perl`, `python`, something else)?  What have you tried?  What gave you a problem?

Comment: i am thinking of using awk ..actually sed is not work inside my shell script when i am trying to remove \n or \

Comment: otherwise of for :--     abc:abc_2,    rick:rick_1,    harry:harry_1,    Christine:Christine_2,  i could have use awk 'BEGIN{RS=",";}{print $1}' ..which is working for me

This input will be in a textfile that i am using inside my shell script .. and then i have to format it to mentioned output

Comment: If the awk command you tried is working for you, why are you asking the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With GNU awk for multi-char RS:

```
$ awk -v RS=',?\\\\n[[:space:]]+' 'gsub(/\\/,"")' file
abc:abc_2
rick:rick_1
harry:harry_1
Christine:Christine_2
```

Answer (score 1):

If the data arrives on a single line laden with backslashes, then I think you can make `sed` work with a little care.

- You need to replace each `\,` sequence with a newline.
- You need to replace each `\n` followed by zero or more blanks with nothing.
- You need to replace each remaining backslash with nothing.
- You need to remove the final newline (so you don't have two of them).

That translates to:

```
echo '\n    \abc\:\abc_2\,\n    \rick\:\rick_1\,\n    \harry\:\harry_1\,\n    \Christine\:\Christine_2\,\n' |
sed -e 's/\\,/\n/g' \
    -e 's/\\n *//g' \
    -e 's/\\//g' \
    -e 's/\n$//'
```

This works correctly for me when I use GNU `sed`.  It doesn't produce the 'correct' output with BSD (Mac OS X) `sed`; I don't get the newlines inserted in the output. This is because BSD `sed` adheres to the POSIX [`sed`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sed.html) specification, which says:

> The escape sequence '`\n`' shall match a `<newline>` embedded in the pattern space. A literal `<newline>` shall not be used in the BRE of a context address or in the substitute function.

And the man page for `sed` on Mac OS X says much the same:

> The escape sequence `\n` matches a newline character embedded in the pattern space.  You cannot, however, use a literal newline character in an address or in the substitute command.

How can you work around this?  Painfully, is probably the answer.  The `y` command can be used because POSIX says:

> [2addr]`y/string1/string2/`
>       Replace all occurrences of characters in *string1* with the corresponding characters in *string2*. If a `<backslash>` followed by an `'n'` appear [sic] in *string1* or *string2*, the two characters shall be handled as a single `<newline>`. If the number of characters in *string1* and *string2* are not equal, or if any of the characters in *string1* appear more than once, the results are undefined. Any character other than `<backslash>` or `<newline>` can be used instead of `<slash>` to delimit the strings. If the delimiter is not 'n', within *string1* and *string2*, the delimiter itself can be used as a literal character if it is preceded by a `<backslash>`. If a `<backslash>` character is immediately followed by a `<backslash>` character in *string1* or *string2*, the two `<backslash>` characters shall be counted as a single literal `<backslash>` character. The meaning of a `<backslash>` followed by any character that is not 'n', a `<backslash>`, or the delimiter character is undefined.

The Mac OS X man page is less verbose and less pedantically precise, but says much the same.  So, I think the trick is to map the `\,` to a character such as <kbd>Control-A</kbd>, and then use `y/^A/\n/` to map the <kbd>Control-A</kbd> to a newline.

That is:

```
echo '\n    \abc\:\abc_2\,\n    \rick\:\rick_1\,\n    \harry\:\harry_1\,\n    \Christine\:\Christine_2\,\n' |
sed -e 's/\\,/^A/g' \
    -e 'y/^A/\n/' \
    -e 's/\\n *//g' \
    -e 's/\\//g' \
    -e 's/\n$//'
```

(where what shown as `^A` is actually a <kbd>Control-A</kbd>; I needed to use <kbd>Control-V</kbd><kbd>Control-A</kbd> in `vim` to get the character entered.)  Anyway, this works correctly with Mac OS X or BSD `sed`.